# Trying add up values but have multiple entries

Tags: excel, match, multiple-columns, vlookup

I am trying to look up the value in one column and pull the number from another column.
Of course, I could use the simple V-lookup or Match.
However, the first column of data has multiple entries that are the same. If I Vlookup it is just going to pull the first number in the second column.

I need to pull each number from the second column and somehow add them together. Despite the fact I have multiple entries. 
If there is a way to consolidate the multiple entries in 1st column while also summing up the numbers in the 2nd, that would be great.

Comment: Have you considered a Pivot Table?

Comment: Yes, you're right a Pivot Table would work well too. I didn't even try that. I just assumed it wouldn't eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) do what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a Pivot Table. To create one, select a cell in your data range (which needs to have column names in the first row. Choose Insert / Pivot Table from the Ribbon and select the New Worksheet option for the location.

[image: example data range]

In the Pivot Table list on the new worksheet, drag the name of the first column to the Row Labels box and the name of the second column to the Values box.  The name in the Values box should turn to Sum of <2nd column name>.

[image: Pivot Table Field List]

The Pivot Table will now show a sorted list of the column 1 values and the summed values of column 2. In the example, you'll see that

[image: Pivot Table]